# Cross-browser positioning background-image

Tags: cross-browser, background-image

I have a problem with positioning a background-image in my main-menu. It looks ok in Chrome, FF and Opera, but that isn't the case with Safari. Please look at the link down below.

http://www.kurvers-bouwbegeleiding.nl/kerndisciplines.php

Please help me!

Chears,

Robin

Answer (score 0):

i think you use a css3 property :

background-position: xpos value ypos value;

try to include space in your picture and place it in right bottom

background-position: right bottom;

Best regard

Nico